# nginx SSL redirect fails

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server

I've got a site I'm serving with nginx. I want it to default to https, so I set up a redirect and also HSTS. If you visit http://getsumbits.com, the request times out. If you visit the https version, HSTS kicks in a future requests work. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name getsumbits.com www.getsumbits.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name getsumbits.com www.getsumbits.com;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  ...
}
```

Comment: Config seems ok at first glance. What else have you left out that may be relevant? Post full nginx config and ensure you've restarted. Check your firewall as well.

Comment: Note that when I went to http://www.getsumbits.com I was redirected to http://getsumbits.com which isn't the behavior I would expect based on the config you posted above. So it's not listening on  Post your EXACT config in, and restart nginx before you do your test.

Answer (score 1):

You should be declaring the server_name in the SSL server block as well,

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name getsumbits.com www.getsumbits.com;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I actually do already, I just didn't paste it into my example. Anything else you can think of? This is a live issue so you can test against the website http://www.getsumbits.com (as long as you remove the site's HSTS cache)

Comment: Based on what you posted, it's the only odd thing I noticed. The way you did it is SOP and should work, unless there's something else preventing nginx listening on port 80. So, I strongly suggest double checking it's listening on port 80 and not firewalled or otherwise blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with the SSL config.

The redirect however can be improved by indicating the Server Name.

In the example below, redirect all HTTP request to https://www.getsumbits.com.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name getsumbits.com www.getsumbits.com;
  # enforce https
  return 301 https://www.getsumbits.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name getsumbits.com www.getsumbits.com;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
}
```

The HSTS does not do the initial "kick-in". What kicks-in is actually your SSL config. What HSTS does is to save in the clients browser the header that this site will always open using HTTPS. Does the next time the client goes to the site, it will no longer go to HTTP even if the client does not enter HTTPS because the browser will already do a local redirect to HTTPS.

PS. Since HTTP is just dying, be sure Port 80 is forwarded properly.